# Retrieving Extended File Properties via delphi

Tags: vba, delphi, word-2010

When you right-click a file in Windows Explorer and select Properties from the menu, a dialog box displays basic properties for that file.

I'm trying to get these properties (keywords, comments, title...) for word files in a folder.

I modified a code that i found somewhere and it works well in vba (MSWord office macro):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim arrHeaders(35)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\Scripts")

For i = 0 To 34
  arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
Next

For Each FileName In objFolder.Items
  For i = 0 To 34
    MsgBox i & vbTab & arrHeaders(i) & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(FileName, i)
  Next
Next

End Sub
```

So I'm trying to make it work in object pascal in delphi. I'm still missing some of the syntax.

I was able to transform half of the syntax:

```
procedure TFormAFDetails.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ObjShell, ObjFolder : Variant;
  FileProp : array of string;
  FName : String;
  I, J : Integer;
begin
    SetLength(FileProp, 35);
    ObjShell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
    ObjFolder := ObjShell.NameSpace('C:\Scripts');

    for I := 0 to 34 do
      FileProp[I] := ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf(ObjFolder.Items,I);

    for FName in ObjFolder.Items do
    begin
      for J := 0 to 34 do
        ShowMessage(FileProp[J]+' : '+ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf(FName,J));
    end;
end;
```

The part "for - in - do" won't work as it says

```
//for -in statement can't operate on collection type 'variant'
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: I'm not sure you really want to translate this code. Why have you hard coded the magic number 35? Why are you wanting to use `Shell.Application` to enumerate files?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know how to get these details using Word.application. But in that case I'll have to open a word file and then pass code 
`WordApp.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties[1].Value;`

but I don't want to open the word file just to get these infos. So I found Shell.Application method. 
Why magic number 35, because there are 35 file properties as mentioned here [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx)

Comment: Well, that's not the only way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am open to suggestions...

Comment: FWIW, there are other articles that mention file property numbers up to 40. I assume this is dependent on the OS used. W2k probably only had 35. There are plenty of examples on the web to see how GetDetailsOf() can be used, also outside Word.

Comment: Calling ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf(ObjFolder.Items,I); and incrementing 'I' until the result is an empty string gave me 289 properties on Win 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question that you ask is:

```
for I := 0 to ObjFolder.Items.Count-1 do
begin
  FName := ObjFolder.Items.Item(I);
  ....
end;
```

The code looks a little odd though, especially the use of that magic value 35.

Comment: I agree that 35 looks odd but thats what they say on [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx) 

Thanx a lot, i think it works... lemme run a few tests..

`for J := 0 to 34 do                                                
     ShowMessage(IntToStr(J)+' '+FileProp[J]+' : '+           ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf(ObjFolder.Items.Item(I),J));
`


   Thanx

Comment: Well it works perfect!! thank you for your expertise :)