# Get image dimensions without loading using meta data

Tags: image, delphi, winapi, metadata

I'd like to get an image's dimensions without actually loading the image, I would like to use the meta data provided in the file.
Is there a `windows api` or something similar that allows me to read this meta data ? a sample would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Look for how to read EXIF information

Comment: Yes, there' a Windows API, but I don't know I to use in delphi, it similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272638/retrieving-extended-file-properties-via-delphi

Comment: Mostly, PNG does not bring EXIF information. EXIF is used mostly for JPG only.

Comment: You can read mayn image file format using the OpenSource library FreeImage (https://freeimage.sourceforge.io/download.html). It includes a wrapper for Delphi. Using that library, you can access the image properties and metadatas. If you decide to go with FreeImage, and get stuck with it, open a new specific question.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried the solution mentioned in your link and at first it seemed like the answer but the result of `ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf` is always empty !, i don't understand why its not working .., this one really seemed like a good and easy solution

Comment: here is how you'd do it in C#, https://pastebin.com/raw/xSCFCES3 I think the Delphi version is very close to this you should be capable of calling the "ExtendedProperty" method on an item.

Comment: @SimonMourier Awesome link! I managed to get it work, it was very easy just 2 lines of code, thank you.

Comment: Post your answer so everyone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of [Simson Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier)'s comment which was a snippet code in *C#*, I managed to make something similar in *Delphi*:

```
uses
  System.Win.ComObj;
var 
  ObjShell, ObjFolder, ObjFile, ObjInfo: Variant;
begin
  ObjShell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');

  // directory of the file to read
  ObjFolder := ObjShell.NameSpace('c:\imagefolders');

  // one of the files in the folder, just the name alone, no path
  ObjFile := ObjFolder.parseName('001.jpg');

  // example: width of the image
  ObjInfo := ObjFile.ExtendedProperty('System.Image.HorizontalSize');

  ShowMessage(ObjInfo);
end;
```

The code was tested in *Delphi 10.4* on *Windows 10*.

Comment: The downsides of this are: it relies on a known filename extension ("001.aaa" won't find any properties although it's still a JPEG file); it only knows a handful of formats (WEBP, HEIC, PSD, XCF, J2C, PCX, TGA are all unsupported); it cannot tell you if a file has more than one picture (ICO, TIFF...); and it depends on the Windows version.